# Unity Scripting Main Menu Not Working? Don't Know Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I made a main menu in unity so now I'm down to the scripting. I have tried the `mouseup` / `mousedown` functions but nothing is wrong with my code but it won't work period no debug logs not errors just plain nothing.
Here's my C# Script to change levels.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {
   public bool Start;
   public bool Quit;

   void OnMouseUp(){
        if(Start)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
        if (Quit)
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
   } 
}
```

This is very simple but I still don't see why it isn't working.

Comment: Did you bind the events to the UI elements?

Comment: Yes i did but still nothing

Comment: Try to debug your code (not logs, set a breakpoint and test if your function gets called). If it's not called, you didn't bind the events correctly. If it get's called you have other problems with your code. It's hard to find the error is this "minimal" setup.

Comment: As Alex suggested you should link the UI element this method, I already see two problems with the class you need to address, first you should set the OnMouseUp access modifier to public or else you wouldn't be able to access it via the UI button, and secondly you should create a button on that UI element you want to click on and set this even on that button, also from the looks of it nothing will happen inside the function since both Start and Quit will stay false unless you change them somewhere else

Comment: @IdoBenShalom Yes They are changed by text that acts as a button and yes i will try making OnMouseUp public. and if that doesn't work i'll try Alex's Suggestion

Comment: @IdoBenShalom I tried making it public,l didn't work either, here i come alex's suggestion

Comment: @alex the breakpoint didn't show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: heres my full application output including the breakpoint you can check it for yourself, it was too long to put here so i put it on mediafire http://www.mediafire.com/file/rpe2r5v8h09172p/Application%20Output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try OnMouseDown

As an event needs to happen first. So the player presses down then upon release the mouse button is up, you need that first click. hope that helps.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the script to a gameobject inside your scene. Also make sure that `Start` or `Quit` are set to true.

Comment: @PheonixVX then your problem is with your trigger event.